# Why do predictions and scores return different results in classification using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, confusion-matrix, multiclass-classification

I wrote a very simple multiclass classifier based on the iris dataset. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC, SVC
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

# Load the data
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Use label_binarize to be multi-label like settings
Y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes = Y.shape[1]

# Add noisy features
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
X = np.concatenate([X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)], axis=1)
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize

# Split into training and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, Y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0 
)

# Create classifier
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(
    make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LinearSVC(random_state=random_state))
)

# Train the model
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

My goal is to predict the values of the test set in 2 ways:

1. Using the `classifier.predict()` function and define `y_pred`.
2. Using the `classifier.decision_function()` to get the scores and then pick the highest one for each instance and define `y_pred_`.

Here is how I did it:

```
# Get the scores for the Test set
y_score = classifier.decision_function(X_test)

# Make predictions
y_pred  = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred_ = label_binarize(np.argmax(y_score, axis=1), [0,1,2])
```

It looks like however that when I try to compute the classification report I get slightly different results, while I would expect to be the same since the predictions are based on the scores obtained from the decision function as it can be seen in the [documentation (line 789)](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09b/sklearn/svm/_base.py#L761). Here are both reports:

```
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred_))

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.54      0.62      0.58        21
           1       0.44      0.40      0.42        30
           2       0.36      0.50      0.42        24

   micro avg       0.44      0.49      0.47        75
   macro avg       0.45      0.51      0.47        75
weighted avg       0.45      0.49      0.46        75
 samples avg       0.39      0.49      0.42        75

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.42      0.38      0.40        21
           1       0.52      0.47      0.49        30
           2       0.38      0.46      0.42        24

   micro avg       0.44      0.44      0.44        75
   macro avg       0.44      0.44      0.44        75
weighted avg       0.45      0.44      0.44        75
 samples avg       0.44      0.44      0.44        75
```

What am I doing wrong? Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant solution so that both reports are identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multilabel classification you should use

```
y_pred_ = np.where(classifier.decision_function(X_test) > 0, 1, 0)
```

to replicate the output of the `predict()` method as in this case the different classes are not mutually exclusive, i.e. a given sample can belong to multiple classes.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, label_binarize
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

# Load the data
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = label_binarize(iris.target, classes=[0, 1, 2])

# Split the data into training and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0
)

# Create classifier
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(
    make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LinearSVC(random_state=0))
)

# Train the model
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make predictions
y_pred  = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred_ = np.where(classifier.decision_function(X_test) > 0, 1, 0)

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
#               precision    recall  f1-score   support
#            0       1.00      1.00      1.00        21
#            1       0.58      0.37      0.45        30
#            2       0.95      0.83      0.89        24
#    micro avg       0.85      0.69      0.76        75
#    macro avg       0.84      0.73      0.78        75
# weighted avg       0.82      0.69      0.74        75
#  samples avg       0.66      0.69      0.67        75

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred_))
#               precision    recall  f1-score   support
#            0       1.00      1.00      1.00        21
#            1       0.58      0.37      0.45        30
#            2       0.95      0.83      0.89        24
#    micro avg       0.85      0.69      0.76        75
#    macro avg       0.84      0.73      0.78        75
# weighted avg       0.82      0.69      0.74        75
#  samples avg       0.66      0.69      0.67        75
```

For multiclass classification you can instead use

```
y_pred_ = np.argmax(classifier.decision_function(X_test), axis=1)
```

as in your code, as in this case the different classes are mutually exclusive, i.e. each sample is assigned to only one class.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

# Load the data
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Split into training and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0
)

# Create classifier
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(
    make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LinearSVC(random_state=0))
)

# Train the model
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make predictions
y_pred  = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred_ = np.argmax(classifier.decision_function(X_test), axis=1)

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
#               precision    recall  f1-score   support
#            0       1.00      1.00      1.00        21
#            1       0.85      0.73      0.79        30
#            2       0.71      0.83      0.77        24
#     accuracy                           0.84        75
#    macro avg       0.85      0.86      0.85        75
# weighted avg       0.85      0.84      0.84        75

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred_))
#               precision    recall  f1-score   support
#            0       1.00      1.00      1.00        21
#            1       0.85      0.73      0.79        30
#            2       0.71      0.83      0.77        24
#     accuracy                           0.84        75
#    macro avg       0.85      0.86      0.85        75
# weighted avg       0.85      0.84      0.84        75
```

Comment: Nice! Useful for me, too. For whom (and if) it may help, the subtle difference is that calling `label_binarize(y)` returns a *multilabel* target, `y` initially being inherently *multiclass* (in the second example y is indeed taken as is). For debugging purposes calling `type_of_target()` might help (from `sklearn.utils.multiclass`).

Answer (score 0):

`OneVsRestClassifier` is assuming that you expect multi-label result, i.e. there may be more than one positive label for a single input. The result is thus different from using `argmax` with `decision_function`.

Try

```py
print(y_pred[0])
print(y_pred_[0])
```

Output:

```
[0 1 1]
[0 0 1]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I saw in the documentation that argmax is used when the predict() method is called. How would you solve this issue then? Furthermore I don't understand what is the problem with more than one positive label since argmax takes the greatest one anyways.